# How to display a VISIO file in ASP.Net web form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visio

I want to show a visio file in a web form  in an ASP.Net web form. I'm using C# and .Net framework 4.5.

I'm creating the visio file dynamically in a web form, according to some data that is stored in a database by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio namespace. Then I save the file in a folder. I can open the file with visio. BUT I need to display it in the web form. (no pdf, no image!)

I added Microsoft Office Visio 12.0 Drawing Control (COM component) to the toolbox, but it is disabled (gray color) so I cannot use it.

Comment: Can you guarantee the person viewing the page will have Visio installed on their computer? After all, Visio isn't exactly a widely distributed program... even most people who have MS Office won't have it. But if this is for a company LAN where you know it's available, maybe something could be done.

Comment: It is for an Interanet not internet users, having visio is not a problem. Moreover, I think we can put a link to download visio viewer

Comment: Probably downloading the Visio file will be your best option, unless you also have a plug-in for Visio files (the same way Adobe needs a plug-in to show acrobat files).

Comment: You can use the free Microsoft Viso Viewer, but this is an ActiveX control, and so is supported in a decreasing number of browsers, plus it is Windows only. In addition, it is only licensed to bon-fide Office license holders (it is installed by Outlook).